# Show that: $ \limsup n \{ n^2 \sqrt{2}\} = \infty $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, equidistribution

Show that:

$$ \overline{\lim} n \{ n^2 \sqrt{2}\} = \infty  $$

Sorry for being so succinct: $n \to \infty$ and $0 < \{ n^2 \sqrt{2} \} < 1$ so I am not sure which effect should win out.

<del>**Hint** use [Tauber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_tauberian_theorems) theorem.  That's not much of a hint but that's all I have to go on.</del>

---

Checking the [lim sup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) is not so difficult, but this does not constitute a proof:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should point out that [] means floor function and {} means fractional remainder.  These are not that universal notations or concepts.

Comment: Must $n$ be integers?  If n may be any real this is trivial as {n^2  root 2} will go from 0 to 1 regulars with sup = 1 so lim sup is lim n = infinity.  With n integer {n^2 root 2} will have sup = 1 if root 2 is normal.

Comment: yes $n \in \mathbb{Z}$  the chart makes it clear it fills the whole triangle, but gets more spread out.

Comment: "I am not sure which effect should win out."  Well, lim n = infinity *should* win because {n^2 root(2)} isn't going to even show up to play.  {n^2 root (2)} "should" bounce about between 0 and 1 with no consistancy and no matter how large n gets 0 < {n^2 root(2)} < 1 so lim sup {n^2 root(2)} *OUGHT* to be 1.  Proving that may require some other insight.

Answer (score 2):

For irrational positive $\alpha,$ the fractional part of $n^2 \alpha$ is equidistributed in the unit interval. This is Satz 13 in [Weyl 1916](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN235181684_0077/PPN235181684_0077___LOG_0036.pdf).

In particular, it is larger than $1/2$ infinitely often.